# Generating a high number of unique random combinations

Tags: php, mysql, random

I have three tables: **Users** with an unique `nickname`, more than four hundred **Names**, 300000 plus **Adjectives** and a ton of possible combinations.

When subscribing, the user can generate an unique, random and hopefully funny nickname by combining a random name with a random adjective. The user clicks a button and Voilà! an exhilarating identity is born.

I select the random names and adjectives by running two queries for each:

```
SELECT FLOOR(RAND() * COUNT(*)) AS `offset` FROM names/adjectives
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM names/adjectives LIMIT offset, 1
```

Then I check if the User was unlucky enough to generate an already existing identity.

```
SELECT COUNT(nickname) FROM users WHERE nickname=:generatedNickname
```

If he was, the poor chap, I loop through this again until it settles on something untaken.

But, as you guys probably already figured out, the growth of the user base also means lengthier loops and more sweat from my feeble EC2 Tier 1 Matchbox. So I came up with a brilliant solution: **What if I pre-generate all the possible combinations and stuff them in a huge table?** This will allow a simple pluck and play operation while I'll be sipping worry free martinis on some anonymous beach or would I? Will my humble LAMP instance tremble and flee at the glorious sight of the humongous tables (both male and female)? Is there any better solution?

Comment: Will you store the combinations by text value or as two foreign keys to those tables? 300K * 400 = some 120 millions combinations. It is not a small table, but if it contains only two ints, then it is manageable (say somewhere around a couple of gigabites) - but do you really expect so many users that average expected number of loops will ever get over 2? (that would mean having some 60M users if my math is not too rusty)

Comment: But if you still fear this, then you can pregenerate thousands of combinations "offline" (during nights for instance) into such table always when it gets "too empty" and use these, no need to generate them all at once.

Comment: @jkavalik The combinations are stored as text. No I will never have that amount of users. The idea that the possibility of a collision is waaay to small also crossed my mind, but it never hurts to ask folks that are more experienced. Thanks, man!

Comment: Using `OFFSET` is not performant -- the processing will read through that many rows to find the 1 you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generating those combinations beforehand will result in a huge amount of data. I do not recommend it. My suggestion would be to use a better source of randomness than `RAND()`. The likeliness of a collision (based on your estimates) is only around `n/120000000`, where `n` is the amount of users, so your loop will not run for a very long time if you *do* get one.

Comment: You just confirmed my thought that there's little possibility of a collision, but like I already told @jkavalik, it never hurts to ask. Could you suggest a better source of randomness, is php `rand` better?

Comment: @Răzvan: PHP's `rand()` is not really superior. If you can, use something like the [`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`](http://php.net/openssl_random_pseudo_bytes), [`random_bytes()`](http://php.net/random_bytes) or [`random_int()`](http://php.net/random_int) functions. Randomness that is cryptographically secure is your best bet for minimizing collisions.

Answer (score 1):

1. Give the Nouns and Adjectives an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id that is the `PRIMARY KEY`.  The other column (nouns/adjectives) should be `UNIQUE`.
2. Keep `COUNT(*)` for each of those two tables somewhere handy.  Recompute these counts if you ever modify the tables.  Do not do `SELECT COUNT(*)` in the code below, it will do a table scan -- not cheap.
3. Use `SELECT noun FROM Nouns WHERE id = CEIL(noun_count * RAND())` to get a random "noun".  Ditto for "adjective".
4. Now we need to check for dups.  You have stored the adjective-noun combo in the user table, correct?  and it is `INDEXed`, correct?  So simply check this combo for already having been used.
5. If it is a dup, then start over.

None of the steps takes long, so even when you have to (rarely) repeat the process, it will not take long.

PS:  I think you will find that `RAND()` is good enough for this task.